# How to find row with min value within a section of a DF

Tags: r, search, dataframe, min

I am looking to find the minimum current value in my DF within a certain interval of my data. This is what I'm trying so far and I'm expecting to get row 49 but it just returns the first row. If I leave the first index in data empty, I get the lowest current value in my whole data set. Any tips on why start:end does not work?

```
start = ceiling(0.4*nrow(data))
end = ceiling(0.8*nrow(data))
min_row = which.min(data[start:end,"current"]) #returns 1 

min_row = which.min(data[,"current"]) #returns 44 (searches all data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `start - 1` when computing `min_row`. Try

```
min_row = which.min(data[start:end,"current"]) + start - 1
#The first value is the index in the list from 'start' to 'end'.
#You need to add 'start - 1' to the value to get the index from beginning of the data.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should at least gives us a link to the data frame or write a code to create a data frame. Please check the code below and see if it works, the comments should make everything clear. :)

```
set.seed(10) # setting seed for reproducability

data <- data.frame(bla=runif(100), current=runif(100))
head(data)

start = ceiling(0.4*nrow(data))
end = ceiling(0.8*nrow(data))

data[start:end, "current"] # <- this is the interval you are looking for the minimum value, its not the whole dat
min_row = which.min(data[start:end, "current"]) ## you get the minimum value of the interval provided. 

# you need to add all of indexes which you have dropped from the start

TRUE_min_row <- min_row + start - 1 

# the -1 part comes from the fact that youre a searching between numbers WITH start[1] included

min_row = which.min(data[ ,"current"]) 

TRUE_min_row == min_row
# as you can see these match
```